# Checking type sizes in C with macros

Tags: c, types, macros, size, c-preprocessor

I'm writing a program that needs to have unsigned types with definite sizes. I need a uint8, uint16, uint32, and uint64, and I need them defined in types.h, in a way that they will always be defined correctly regardless of platform.

My question is, how can I check the sizes of different types on each platform using preprocessor macros, so that I can define my custom types correctly in the types.h header?

Answer (score 4):

C has standard `typedefs` for these. Do not define your own. They are called `intN_t` and `uintN_t` where `N` is 8, 16, 32, 64, etc. Include `<stdint.h>` to get them.

If you're using an ancient compiler that lacks `stdint.h`, you can simply provide your own with the appropriate typedefs for whatever broken platform you're working with. I would wager that on any non-embedded target you encounter without `stdint.h`:

- `CHAR_BIT` is 8.
- `sizeof(char)` is 1. <-- I'd wager even more on this one... ;-)
- `sizeof(short)` is 2.
- `sizeof(int)` is 4.
- `sizeof(long long)`, if the type exists, is 8.

So just use these as fill-ins for broken systems.

Comment: `inttypes.h` handily goes along with these types too.  These headers are definitely in POSIX, but I wasn't aware they were in the C standard too.  Neat.

Comment: If the ancient compiler happens to be MSVC you can use this: http://msinttypes.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/stdint.h

Comment: if you use the standard integer types as fill-ins, you should also use the preprocessor to verify the correct ranges: `#if UINT_MAX != 0xFFFFFFFF␤#error "int is not 32-bit"␤#endif`

Answer (score 1):

```
   312 #define SDL_COMPILE_TIME_ASSERT(name, x)               \

   313        typedef int SDL_compile_time_assert_ ## name[(x) * 2 - 1]


   316 SDL_COMPILE_TIME_ASSERT(uint8, sizeof(Uint8) == 1);

   317 SDL_COMPILE_TIME_ASSERT(sint8, sizeof(Sint8) == 1);

   318 SDL_COMPILE_TIME_ASSERT(uint16, sizeof(Uint16) == 2);

   319 SDL_COMPILE_TIME_ASSERT(sint16, sizeof(Sint16) == 2);

   320 SDL_COMPILE_TIME_ASSERT(uint32, sizeof(Uint32) == 4);

   321 SDL_COMPILE_TIME_ASSERT(sint32, sizeof(Sint32) == 4);

   322 SDL_COMPILE_TIME_ASSERT(uint64, sizeof(Uint64) == 8);

   323 SDL_COMPILE_TIME_ASSERT(sint64, sizeof(Sint64) == 8);
```

Checkout SDL https://hg.libsdl.org/SDL/file/d470fa5477b7/include/SDL_stdinc.h#l316 they statically assert size at compile time. Like @Mehrdad say is can't be platform independant if your target doesn't have 64 bits integer.

Answer (score 0):

You can't even guarantee that all those types will *exist* on your platform (say, there might not even *be* a 64-bit integer), so you can't possibly write platform-independent code to detect them at compile-time.

Comment: I am aware that the 64 bit integer will be problematic on some platforms.

Comment: Well, it's not just 64-bit -- if you're *truly* writing platform-independent C code, all that is guaranteed is that `sizeof(long long int) >= sizeof(long int) >= sizeof(short int)`... but they could all, for all practical purposes, be 16-bit! So you must necessarily assume some nonstandard things before you can write code like this.

Comment: No. C requires `ULONG_MAX` to be at least 2^32-1 and `ULLONG_MAX` to be at least 2^64-1.

Comment: That's funny -- I specifically remember reading in my C book that the only guarantee made is the one I wrote. Seem like you're right, though; funny that the book was wrong...

Comment: Damn it all, I'm using pstdint.